# Regular Expression for tags

Tags: regex

I need to write regular expression that will match any pair of tags `<(.*?)>.*?</\1>` but only if there is no other pair tags between them. Tag names are variable length.

Comment: You probably don't actually want to use regex for this. Use an actual parser that was designed to do the task at hand.

Comment: What you have there *should* work for just that, since they are all `.*?` (least number of matching characters) rather than `.*` (largest number of matching characters).

Comment: parsing tags with REGEX is very risky.. it'll never behave the way you want.  use  a proper parser.

Comment: A regex that works today will be borked tomorrow and if you're lucky you'll notice that it has broken. This question is posed so frequently on stackoverflow that you really have to work to post a question asking about this and ignore the dozen plus answers that the site puts right in your face. Even jokes about people posting "regex my tags" question have become passé. Congratulations, Nick, if there was a badge for obdurate laziness, you'd have gotten it.

Comment: We don't know the task at hand.  Nick may very well be dealing with data that is not proper HTML or XML and therefore cannot be handled by an HTML or XML parser.  We don't know whether the task at hand needs to work with any HTML or XML the user may throw at it, or whether the task at hand is a quick editing job of a specific file in a text editor.

Comment: Obligatory "Don't parse HTML with Regex" link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Nick, you need to state which language or editor you're using this regex with.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily exclude nested tags by excluding the angle bracket needed to open them:

```
<([^<>]+)>[^<]*</\1>
```

This regex won't work if the opening tag has attributes.  If you want to allow those, try this:

```
<(\S+)[^<>]*>[^<]*</\1>
```

Comment: Thanks to kiamlaluno for fixing my typo.  No regex can handle every possible situation.  Its hard to be more specific unless nick posts a link to a sample file.

Comment: +1 good idea. Does it works also on `<tag> <tag></tag><tag></tag></tag>`?

Comment: This regex is specifically intended *not* to match nested tags.

Answer (score 1):

You simply should not do this with regex.  [However, don't take my word for it.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: Who says nick is parsing HTML?  Maybe he's just fixing up something with a text editor that happens to support regular expressions but doesn't have a built-in HTML parser.

Comment: @Jan Goyvaerts You make a fair point.  Nick needs to provide more detail in his question.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you maintain the "Only if there is no other tags between them" this is easy.

```
<\s*([^>]+?)\s*>[^<]*</\s*\1\s*>
```

Comment: The OP said "no other pair tags between them".

Comment: I made the assumption that what is being supplied is valid markup. This regex would only work with that assumption holding true. "Pair of tags" and "tags" are equivalent in such a case.

Comment: Not exactly. `<br/>`, `<img/>` and other similar tags do not operate with pairs.

Comment: It also assumes the content has no comments (which aren't technically tags, IIRC), no CDATA sections, and the tags have no attributes, right?  Any other assumptions that might cause problems in the context of this question?

Comment: And how would one guarantee the assumed invariant that "there are no other [pair] tags between them? With a regexp? It's elephants all the way down.